# Change Position of notifications

Tags: windows-10, notifications

Is there a way to change the position of the notifications from lower right to upper right? My chat-prompt is always on the lower right and when I get a message, it hides it. Also when I expand a tray icon the notifications hide it too.

I found a solution [here](http://winaero.com/blog/move-notification-toasts-to-top-or-bottom-of-the-screen-in-windows-10/), but it doesn't work. Is there currently a working solution? A different registry hack maybe?

Answer (score 6):

Disabled by design. Registry change does not work after RTM release. There doesn't seem to be any utilities to change it either.
I would appreciate a solution if you find one.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/windows-10-enterprise-2015-ltsb-os-notification/24895db1-e588-4024-b888-24a522635cdf

Comment: I'd like a way to change this too...I'd rather they were on the left since I have my taskbar vertically on the right and notifications always hinder my workflow on the bottom right.